# Use jqgrid to filter in the same way searching is done

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, visualforce, free-jqgrid

Let me see if I can explain this...

I have a product grid, searching works fine, I have set up a custom button to filter on specific items in the json that are not in the grid, right now I am making an ajax call (using VisualForce) to get the json then I'm storing it in a global variable before using the json to load the grid, I then load the grid. When a filter is chosen I build a temp array of the json that contains the filter and then set the product grid to the new array. I then have a reset so if the filter is changed or removed it will first get the global that I set earlier and the re-apply a new filter, however when I `clearGridData` it empties my global variable as well so when I click reset it just reloads the grid with zero rows.

I am guessing what I am doing is the wrong way to do it so I am wondering how does the search work, you search for an item it shows only the matches in the grid and then simply pressing reload it reloads all records back into grid. I need my filter to work somewhat the same.

```
        var cart = [];
        var cartMade = false;
        var cartSubmitted = false;
        var sfOpportunityId;
        var filteredProducts = [];
        var fullProductList = [];

        function GetFilteredProducts(){
            //reload products with filtered array
            var products = $("#productsTable").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
            var selected = $("#filterByFieldDropDown option:selected").val();
            switch(selected){
                case "common" :
                    filteredProducts = $.grep(products, function(value) {
                    return value.IsCommonItem == true;
                    });
                    break;
                case "sos-common" :
                    filteredProducts = $.grep(products, function(value) {
                    return value.IsCommonSosItem == true;
                    });
                    break;
                case "uncommon" :
                    filteredProducts = $.grep(products, function(value) {
                    return value.IsCommonItem == false;
                    });
                    break;
            }
            RemoveProductFilter();
            $("#productsTable").jqGrid('clearGridData')
                .jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: filteredProducts})
                .trigger("reloadGrid");
        }

        function RemoveProductFilter() {
            $("#productsTable").jqGrid('clearGridData')
                .jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: fullProductList})
                .trigger("reloadGrid");

            $("#filter-dialog-form").dialog("close");
        }

        function QueryServerForProducts() {
            $(".spinner").show();   
            var ajaxCall = '{!$RemoteAction.AddProductsCustom.GetProducts}';
            sfOpportunityId = requestQueryString("id")
            GetCart();
            // Get Products and put them into product grid
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                ajaxCall, 
                sfOpportunityId,
                function(result, event){
                    if (event.status) {
                        $(".spinner").hide();
                        var parsedResult = JSON.parse(DecodeAscii(result));
                        fullProductList = parsedResult;
                        CreateProductGrid(parsedResult);
                    } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                        ShowErrorLabel("ERROR in ajax call(" + ajaxCall + "): \n" + event.message);
                    } else {
                        ShowWarningLabel("Problem w/ ajax call(" + ajaxCall + "): \n" + event.message);
                    }
                }, 
                {escape: true} 
            );
        }

        function CreateProductGrid(result){
            var previouslySelectedRow = null;
            var rowIsSelected = null;
            var previousRowIsSelected = null;
            var currentRowId;
            var currentCount;
            var cancelEditing = function(theGrid) {
                var lrid;
                if (typeof previouslySelectedRow !== "undefined") {
                    // cancel editing of the previous selected row if it was in editing state.
                    // jqGrid hold intern savedRow array inside of jqGrid object,
                    // so it is safe to call restoreRow method with any id parameter
                    // if jqGrid not in editing state
                    theGrid.jqGrid('restoreRow', previouslySelectedRow);

                    // now we need to restore the icons in the formatter:"actions"
                    lrid = $.jgrid.jqID(previouslySelectedRow);
                    $("tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-edit").show();
                    $("tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-save, " + "tr#" + lrid + " div.ui-inline-cancel").hide();
                }
            };

            $("#productsTable").jqGrid({
                    data: result,
                    datatype: "local",
                    colNames: [
                        'Add', 'Product Name', 'Product Code', 'Customer Price'
                    ],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: "actions", template: "actions", width: 50, formatoptions:{
                            delbutton: false,
                            editbutton: false
                        }},
                        { name: 'ProductName', index: 'ProductName', width: 650, search: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']} },
                        { name: 'ProductCode', index: 'ProductCode', width: 150, search: true, searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','bw','bn','cn','nc','ew','en']} },
                        { name: 'UnitPrice', index: 'UnitPrice', width: 100, search: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions:{decimalSeparator:".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$"}}
                    ],
                    rowNum: 25,
                    rowList: [15, 25, 50, 100],
                    pager: true,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    sortname: 'ProductName',
                    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
                    sortorder: 'asc',
                    localReader: {id: "ProductId" },
                    caption: "Products",
                    navOptions: {
                        edit: false,
                        add: false,
                        del: false,
                        searchtext: "<span class='ui-pg-button-text'>Search</span>",
                        refreshtext: "<span class='ui-pg-button-text'>Reload</span>",
                        iconsOverText: true
                    },
                    inlineNavOptions: {
                        edit: false,
                        add: false,
                        del: false
                    },
                    searching: {
                        overlay: false,
                        multipleSearch: true,
                        closeAfterSearch: true,
                        closeOnEscape: true,
                        showQuery: true
                    },
                    actionsNavOptions: {
                        addToCarticon: "fa-shopping-cart",
                        addToCarttitle: "Add product to the cart",
                        custom: [
                            { action: "addToCart", position: "first", onClick: function (options) { 
                                var rowData = $('#productsTable').getLocalRow(options.rowid);
                                var cartButton = $("#jAddToCartButton_"+options.rowid).find("span");
                                if(cartButton.hasClass("fa-ban")){
                                    DeleteProductFromOpportunity(JSON.stringify(rowData));
                                    cart = $.grep(cart, function(value) {
                                      return value.ProductId !== rowData.ProductId;
                                    });
                                    //reload cart with new array
                                    reloadCart();
                                    cartButton.removeClass("fa-ban");
                                    cartButton.addClass("fa-shopping-cart");
                                }
                                else if(cartButton.hasClass("fa-shopping-cart")){
                                    cart.push(rowData);
                                    //reload cart with new array
                                    reloadCart();
                                    cartButton.removeClass("fa-shopping-cart");
                                    cartButton.addClass("fa-ban");
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    loadComplete: function() {
                        //for each object in cart
                        //if product ID matches product Id in product 
                        //grid then set button to a cancel icon
                        if(cart.length !== 0){
                            var cartIds = [];
                            var jsonCart = JSON.stringify(cart);
                            var parsedJsonCart = JSON.parse(jsonCart);
                            var productsInCart = $.grep(parsedJsonCart, function(el, i){
                                cartIds.push(el.ProductId);
                            });

                            var currentRows = $('#productsTable').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data')
                            var shownProductsThatAreInCart = $.grep(currentRows, function (el, i) {
                                return $.inArray(el.ProductId, cartIds) !== -1;
                            });

                            if(shownProductsThatAreInCart.length > 0){
                                var rowIds = $(this).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                                $.each(rowIds, function(k, v) {
                                    rowData = $('#productsTable').getLocalRow(v);

                                    if($.inArray(rowData['ProductId'], cartIds) !== -1){
                                        //alert("Matched Product:\nRowData['ProductId'] = " + rowData['ProductId'] + "\nto\nProduct in cart: " + cartIds.Id);
                                        var cartButton = $("#jAddToCartButton_"+v).find("span");
                                        cartButton.removeClass("fa-shopping-cart");
                                        cartButton.addClass("fa-ban");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .jqGrid('navGrid')
                .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
                    iconsOverText: true,
                    caption:"<span class='ui-pg-button-text'>Filter</span>",
                    buttonicon: "fa-filter",
                        onClickButton: function() {
                            InitializeFilterDialog();
                            $("#filter-dialog-form").dialog("open");
                        },
                    title:"Filter",
                    position: "first"
                })
                .jqGrid("navButtonAdd", {
                        iconsOverText: true,
                        caption:"<span class='ui-pg-button-text'>View Cart</span>",
                        buttonicon: "fa-shopping-cart",
                            onClickButton: function() {
                                InitializeProductCartDialog();
                                ShowCart();
                            },
                        title:"View Cart"
                });
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow you because you don't included and test data or the demo. If the input data have some fields by which you need to filter then you could just set `postData.filters` and `search: true` to filter the grid. You can combine the filtering with `filterToolbar` if needed, but it's not required. The grid will display the filtered data. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) from the README of 4.13.1 version of free jqGrid for example.

Comment: the filter in your demo filters on items in the column, I dont want to do that, I want to filter on data in the json, I have a field in the json called IsCommon and it may be set to true, I dont want that piece of data as a column on my grid, so I have created this custom filter button that opens a dialog and then changes the data in the grid using the functions RemoveProductFilter and GetFilteredProducts. I will try to build a demo.

Comment: Sorry, but you permanently use JSON in the wrong way. One don't need to have any column in the grid to filter by the column. Free jqGrid allows you to filter by **properties** of input data. You need just add `additionalProperties: ["prop1", "prop2"]` or `additionalProperties: ["prop1", {name:"prop2", sorttype:"number"}]` to be able to sort or to filter by the properties. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalProperties.htm). Moreover one can use custom filter or custom sorting function in any column.

Comment: Okay here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/36wkfzs4/ You can see that you can filter for common but you can not clear the filter back to the fullData nor can you change the filter, both clear filter and change filter results in zero rows.

Comment: ok nevermind, the fix was I need to clone/merge the array rather then set the array equal to another array `fullData = $.merge([], mydata);` https://jsfiddle.net/y3llowjack3t/36wkfzs4/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you to load all the data and just apply the filter on the grid. The fixed code could be the following:

```
var mydata = [
        {"id":"1","invdate":"2010-05-24","name":"test","note":"note","tax":"10.00","total":"2111.00","isCommon":"true","isCommonSos":"true"},
        ...
        {"id":"29","invdate":"2007-09-01","name":"test3","note":"note3","amount":"400.00","tax":"30.00","total":"430.00","isCommon":"true","isCommonSos":"false"}
    ],
    $grid = $("#productsTable");

$grid.jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10,20,30],
       colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
       colModel:[
           {name:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
           {name:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date", formatter:"date"},
           {name:'name', width:100},
           {name:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float", formatter:"number"},
           {name:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
           {name:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},        
           {name:'note', width:100, sortable:false}        
       ],
       pager: true,
       viewrecords: true,
       caption: "Filtering Array Data",
       additionalProperties: ["isCommon", "isCommonSos"],
       iconSet: "fontAwesome"
});

$("#applyFilter").on("click", function() {
    GetFilteredProducts();
});

$("#clearFilter").on("click", function() {
    var p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    delete p.postData.filters;
    p.search = false;
    $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
});

function GetFilteredProducts(){
  //reload products with filtered array
  var selected = $("#filterByFieldDropDown").val(),
      p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam");

  switch(selected){
    case "common" :
      p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
          groupOp: "AND",
          groups: [],
          rules: [{field: "isCommon", op: "eq", data: "true"}]
      });
      break;
    case "sos-common" :
      p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
          groupOp: "AND",
          groups: [],
          rules: [{field: "isCommonSos", op: "eq", data: "true"}]
      });
      break;
    case "uncommon" :
      p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify({
          groupOp: "AND",
          groups: [],
          rules: [{field: "isCommon", op: "eq", data: "false"}]
      });
      break;
  }
  p.search = true;
  $grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

See the fixed demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/36wkfzs4/2/.

Free jqGrid support filtering and sorting by any *additional properties* of input data in the same way like by columns. If you need to filter/sort by string properties you can just add the list of properties in `additionalProperties`, like I used `additionalProperties: ["isCommon", "isCommonSos"]` in the above demo. You can use the properties as the value of `sortname` too, to force sorting by the property.

If you would like to interpret the content of the property as number or integer then you can use another form of `additionalProperties`: and object with two properties `name` and `sorttype`. For example you can remove the column `id` and to use `additionalProperties: ["isCommon", {name: "id", sorttype: "integer"}, "isCommonSos"]`. To interpret the data as date you should add `formatter: "date"`. You can specify `formatoptions` with `srcformat` and `newformat` additionally. In general the format of `additionalProperties` for numbers and date could be subset of settings used in `colModel`. You can just move some columns, which you want hold always hidden to `additionalProperties` and all will work in the same way like with hidden columns, but the DOM of the grid will be smaller.

Comment: I think if I wasn't writing this in SalesForce that this solution could work but because I am at the mercy of SF I am getting an error by doing the filtering this way. The alert says: `Type Error: Cannot  read property 'reader' of undefined.` and the console error says: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxxxxx.salesforce.com/_ui/common/request/servlet/JsLoggingServlet. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://xxxxxxx.visual.force.com' is therefore not allowed access.` The good news tho is I was able to get it to work by cloning the array.

Comment: @Noctane: Please inform me, which steps I should do to reproduce the problem on https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/36wkfzs4/2/

Comment: I don't think you can, I can't put salesforce code into jsfiddle, your answer was correct though and I wanted to say thank you for taking the time to show me how to do it. It is just a shame I cannot make it work in visualforce.

Comment: @Noctane: You are welcome! If you have alternative online demo which I could debug, you can send it me via email oleg.kiriljuk@ok-soft-gmbh.com. Moreover I'd recommend you to use the latest 4.13.1 version which I published recently.

Comment: Will do, as far as an online demo; I wont be able to do that as the code is behind my organization which requires credentials to get to. I suppose I could go get a personal edition and write all the code there but it's almost not worth the effort, I hope you understand :) Thanks again!

Comment: @Noctane: You are welcome! The error `Cannot read property 'reader' of undefined` exist typically if columns of `colModel` are not correctly defibed, but it was one bug in free jqGrid which is fixed in 4.13.1. It could be the origin of your problem. Can you verify which version you used in your tests: 4.13.0 or 4.13.1?

Comment: Ok so upgrading to 4.13.1 made the error go away but now nothing happens, the filter is never applied and there are no errors at all.

Comment: @Noctane: I'm afraid, one need debug the corresponding demo to demystify the problem.

Comment: Yea, I put all my actual json into a demo and it works just fine, I am assuming its something with VisualForce.

Comment: @Noctane: In any way if you would suspect that free jqGrid works incorrectly (have a bug in some specific environment) then you can prepare the demo, which use non-minimized version of free jqGrid and to send me the URL with the short test case. I can fix the bug only if I can debug the problem and clear localize the reason.

Comment: @Noctane: The error "Cannot read property 'reader' of undefined" in 4.13.0 and no filtering in 4.13.1 could be for example if you use wrong values of "field" in `postData.filters` of if you would forget to include the fields in `additionalProperties` array. The value of `"field"` should be either the `name` from `colModel` or from `additionalProperties`.