# jqGrid height:auto with reloadGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that loads beautifully to my page with the grid parameter `height:'auto'`.  The height of grid exaclty adjusts to the number of rows.  I have it set to just load one page, no matter how many rows, so there is no max-height, and no pager.

I have a method to reload the grid, which also works very well.  The problem is, the number of rows is often changed after the `reloadGrid` has finished, but the height of the grid stays the same as when it was initially loaded.  Since `height:'auto'` is set, there is no scrollbar available, and extra rows are hidden and unreachable.  What I would like is to have the height of the grid to automatically re-adjust to fit the number of rows after grid data has reloaded.

I am using the jqGrid Guriddo version.

Thanks

Comment: Could you verify that the same problem exist with [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) 4.13.2 too? You need just temporary change the URL to 3 jqGrid files (`ui.jqgrid.css`, `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and `grid.locale-en.min.js`) to URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). Have the grid pager? How it looks after the reloading? Which value have `rowNum` option?

Comment: @Oleg your free jqGrid works!  For this grid I have no pager and have not set the rowNum option.

Comment: @Oleg you are really a mastermind.  I will continue dev with your free jqGrid.  I hope to be able to contribute to your project, although I am just a novice!

Comment: I would recommend you to read to post your standard code. I cold gives you some tips how it could be improved to use the current new features of free jqGrid. Which CSS framework you use (jQuery UI, Bootstrap or both)? Do you use already Font Awesome? Do you use `loadonce: true` or you have a lot of rows (>100000) and have implemented server side paging, sorting and filtering?

Comment: Well it is kind of a long story.  I had set up many pages and grids a few years ago with the jqGrid package.  I made my own server side script to return XML data.  It has sorting, filtering, and paging available, serving about 100 grids.  I am creating new pages now, so I thought I would use the newest jqGrid available, that's why I downloaded Guriddo, not knowing the license had changed.  Also building my new server side script for JSON data. Anyway, loadonce is not true.  jquery-ui css only.  Don't know Font Awesome.  For this project, we just want 1 page of data.

Comment: Then I'd recommend you just to return **all data at once** from the server and to use simple JSON format like `[{...}, .... {...}]` with objects {...} which have named properties without spaces. You can use `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` options. Use `rowNum: 20, page: true`. To have more nice icons you should include FreeAwesome CSS on the page and use `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option. Read more [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). I recommend `cmTemplate: { autoResizable: true }, autoResizing: { compact: true }` and to try  `autoresizeOnLoad: true`.

Comment: You helped me fix my JSON format here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619277/jqgrid-custom-json-data-no-error-but-not-showing-data.  It is still basically that format, although there are more columns now.  We need to show all rows on the initial load.  Usually there will be between 20 and 100 rows.  I will try these options you mention here, the fontAwesome looks... Awesome!  Thanks a lot!  Only difference I see in the CSS in your rows are slightly shorter by default then the Gurrido, but I guess that is all adjustable.

Comment: You are welcome! I see the old question. The first thing which I'd recommend you to change is the format of dates which you send to jqGrid. It's better to use `"2016-04-14"` instead of `"04/14/2016"` and allow jqGrid to convert the date in the correct format: by adding `sorttype: "date", formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "m/d/Y" }` properties. It allows jqGrid to sort and to filter the content of the column. I recommend you to add `template: "number"` to columns `JobNum` and `QNTYOrdered`.

Comment: If the values from `JobNum` column are **unique**, then you should add `key: true` to the column `JobNum`. The rowids will be used by jqGrid with the content from the column. You can return the server data like `[{"id": 38863, "Ship_Date": "2016-04-14", "InsertorLabel": "Insert", "Customer": "Cust", "JobNum": 38863, ...}]` or without `id` property if the `JobNum` contains already the required value and `key: true` is set. I recommend to remove all `index` properties from `colModel` and use `cmTemplate: {width:20}` instead of usage the same property in all columns. You can remove `loadError`

Comment: Free jqGrid provide default implementation of `loadError`. Thus the user will see the error message in case of error without `loadError`. You can *overwrite* default implementation of `loadError`, but not with the implementation which you currently use. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa.htm) or [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa1.htm) as examples of the usage.

Comment: I like your suggestion for JSON format.  That is actually what I thought I should be able to do originally. I found that I always needed the exact same number of columns in my `colModel` as was returned from the server. So I made my data that way.  I was expecting to be able to load the entire table (for example 20 columns), but only use a few columns (say 5) in the `colModel` and even re-ordering the columnes using colModel, but I never was able to do it.

Comment: If you want to display (to show the user) only come columns then you should include only the columns in `colModel`. If you want to save additional properties returned from the server in the local `data` too then you can use `additionalProperties` parameter. See for example [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35948567/315935) or [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/forceClientSorting.htm) and [this one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog1.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is missing `rowNum`. The old (original) jqGrid have some options which are misunderstandable. I fixed such problems in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/) - the fork, which I develop.

For example the default value of `rowNum` is is 20 (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). Even if the grid have **no pager** then the same `rowNum: 20` value is used and the grid just display the first 20 rows without any tips or warning to the user. It's very bad. Free jqGrid for example increase the value of `rowNum` from 20 to `maxRowNum` (which value is 10000 by default) if no pager is defined. By the way, free jqGrid allows to define the pager, by `pager: true` or `toppager: true` without placing empty `<div>` like `<div id="pager"></div>` and the usage of `pager: "#pager"`. Some more small changes like above are described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/SMALL-improvements-in-the-usage-of-jqGrid) and in [this one](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods).

If you do want to continue to use commercial Guriddo jqGrid JS (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) instead of upgrading to free jqGrid then you should just add `rowNum: 10000` to your grid to fix the described problem.

Comment: Just FYI, the setting `rowNum:10000` did fix the problem with Guriddo, although I'll be continuing with the free jqGrid.